# CSS, Javascript functionality issue relating to styled input buttons on newer browsers? (IE 8/9, FF 9)

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I'm working on a site where I have input buttons (styled using CSS) that are a part of a form.
For example, see below for sample code

```
<input type="submit" name="buttonSave" value="save" id="buttonsavejs" class="button_image button_style"/>
```

I've just found an issue where if a user clicks on the button, it moves a few pixels below and then expected action takes place *intermittently*. But *intermittent*, I mean that sometimes it works (redirects the user to the next page) and sometimes nothing happens.

The developer who worked on this previously hasn't documented his code much, so I'm trying to work from scratch here (so excuse the lack of details). Anyway, after testing the code, it appears that the issue lies with how newer browsers are rendering the css and javascript.

Here's a snippet of the javascript behind the button's functionality:

```
$("#buttonsavejs").click(function(){
        $("#main").unbind("submit").submit();
```

And the CSS that styles the button

```
.button_style {
  height:28px;
  margin-left:10px;
  position:relative;
  right:10px;
  top:-23px;
  width:100px;
}

.button_image {
  background-image:url(http://some_image);
  border-bottom-width:0;
  border-color:initial;
  border-image:initial;
  border-left-width:0;
  border-right-width:0;
  border-style:initial;
  border-top-width:0;
  display:block;
  font-size:1px;
  line-height:1px;
  outline-color:initial;
  outline-style:none;
  outline-width:initial;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  overflow-y:hidden;
  position:relative;
  text-indent:-9999px;
}
```

Also, I noticed a very similar question asked here: [Why do mouse clicks not always work for styled input buttons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8375920/why-do-mouse-clicks-not-always-work-for-styled-input-buttons)

Another piece of what I've been able to find out so far. In IE 9's developer tools, if I switch the Document Mode to anything other than IE 8 or 9, the button behaves as it should. So one line of thinking I have is to set the X-UA-Compatible to IE 7 and see if that resolves it as, apparently, that's how the document mode in IE works: [IE8 browser mode vs document mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950598/ie8-browser-mode-vs-document-mode)

**Question**: After testing in FF (earlier versions < 9.0), IE 7, I noticed that the button works as it should. But in FF 9, Chrome 16, IE 8/9, it behaves as described above.
Has anyone run into a similar problem and any advice on what I should be watching out for?

Comment: The answer posted to that question seems to point you in the right direction (the `position: relative` stuff). What have you done to explore that?

Comment: Just curious, why are you resetting initial values to `initial` here? Do you set them to other values for more general styles?

Comment: @BoltClock: Not sure why it was coded this way. But I don't think this is connected to the issue.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I tested it using IE's developer and firebug and it doesn't seem to make a difference in this case (even if I remove it completely).

Comment: i have a similar issue. i also beleive it is FF browser version issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8845536/jquery-min-conflict-with-input-submit

Comment: Maybe an unbind issue? Have you tried swapping a normal submit button with a javascript-created button, once the page loads, so you can leave the unbind out? It would then fall back to the more button if javascript isn't switched on.

Comment: are there styles for this input that affect the :active pseudo-selector? .button_image:active or .button_style:active ? if there is any positioning on that, then it will cause your issue.

Comment: Why do you need to unbind the submit event?

Comment: Try getting rid of all superfluous styling in .button_image which may trigger bugs.  I'd start getting rid of the position:relative and the unnecessary display:block,  simplify all borders to "border:none;",  overflow-x+y to "overflow:hidden;".  Change text-indent to -999em.  Then see.

Comment: wow thats some ugly css right there! 'border:none;'? :)
And I'd start by blaming jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Easy fix:

first, don't use :

```
<input type="button" />
```

use

```
<button type="button">bla bla bla</button> // you can use type="submit"
```

and in script :

```
$("#buttonsavejs").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // this stops the button from doing it's default action, aka submit.
```