# firefox 9 & jquery bug with input submit

Tags: jquery, html, submit

i have a strange problem with an input submit in my html form

```
<input type="submit" name="_save" value="save"  />
```

when i click this submit button it disappears and doesn't submit form.i click it second time it works and appears again!

i found that if i remove the js link to jquery.min.js this problem goes . but i need jquery.min.js

am i doing something wrong? why is the jquery.min.js not working with this simple input submit button?!

-----UPDATE----

after some investigation it seems this issue doesn't happen in chrome & is related to newer FF version 9.0.1 (linux).

can someone confirm if FF 9 has a bug rendering input submit while using jquery?

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the attribute name being deprecated, there is nothing wrong with that code.

Comment: has to be something else...maybe you are attaching something to input tags in your jQuery

Comment: It has to be something else. Can you put up a demo or a jsFiddle?

Comment: that is a lot of script, it is highly possible there is a conflict.  you should try to inspect the submit element in chrome and figure out what of all that stuff is affecting it

Comment: hmm -it seems this issue is only related to firefox browser on linux. when i tried application in chrome it worked correctly. very strange.

Comment: i use firefox 9.0.1 on opensuse 12.1.

Comment: if i comment all other js except the jquery.min.js the problem still exists. so definitely it is a firefox 9 /jquer.min.js issue

Comment: i hope someone could confirm this with a simple test with firefox 9.0.1 on linux and jquer.min.js.. can someone confirm if it can replicate this issue?

Comment: similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840271/css-javascript-functionality-issue-relating-to-styled-input-buttons-on-newer-br